# How to test a function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Want to create functions to be used in Helpers or Schedulers but I don't know the method on where to create these functions to ensure they work.

For example is there a way I can run via terminal php artisan functionname and it runs the function i created so once I know it's working and giving me the results i need i can place it in one of my Helpers.

Thanks in advance.

I usually just place the function in a route and then access the route via url to test the response of the function which is silly and not the correct method.

Comment: For test a function in Laravel, you can create a unit test in Laravel. Unit tests are automated tests that check the functionality of individual parts of your application, such as functions or methods.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing

Comment: you can use `tinker` if you want an interactive shell ... `php artisan tinker`

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a command

2- Register it with Laravel by adding it to the commands array in the app/Console/kernel.php

3- run it via terminal (`php artisan function:name`)
you can then move into a help or scheduler